Why do my gas stove's burners start sparking when I lower the gas?
The burners on my GE stove ignite fine, but when I lower the gas all the burners start sparking.

I have a GE too. Lower the flame in the other direction. Seriously. Just try it and you'll understand.

@MTA, can you elaborate? Does the gas lower when turning toward the off position (adjacent to the ignite position)?

I have a GE range that does not behave that way.   From off, you turn the knob about 90° and there's absolutely nothing.  Then about 5° of spark with no gas, then about 5° of spark with full gas, and after that it goes from high to low as you turn it.  It could be that MTA's and OP's are not like mine.  But you need to believe that OP has never used a gas range before, is not reading the labels on the knob, and came here to ask without even spending 15 seconds trying things.  That's pretty cynical.

@jay613 That is the standard. Why? Because ignition is most successful with full gas output, plus if you just start turning things form an Off position you will pass through ignition so even if you go a little fast and don't wait for the flame you have a good chance (but not a guarantee...which is where the automatic clicking/igniter comes in) of lighting it in that first turn of the knob. If it was Off->Low->High->Ignite then people would more often turn on the gas on low, not realize it had not ignited and end up with a potentially dangerous problem.

@isherwood That's right, the flame on my GE lowers over a very narrow range near the ignite range. I witnessed a relative unfamiliar with my stove trying to regulate the flame within this 5 degree range and getting ignition clicks. I told her to turn it the other way. "Oh" was all she said. Cynical or not (!) that solved her problem.

Some GE stoves go from High -> Low as you rotate the knob, others go from Low -> High. It is super-confusing if you switch cooktops. I think it has to do with the original manufacturer, which was historically a separate company. (Y'know there are only five appliance companies any more... Electrolux, Whirlpool, Samsung, LG and Haier. GE was acquired by Haier in 2016. [https://academy.fredsappliance.com/news/appliance-brands-owns/] )

@SteveI Exactly. The GE that I own (and perhaps the OP's) goes briefly low with n spark to high with a spark, then high no spark, then eventually back to low. There's a narrow range between high with spark and off where you have flame adjustment with no spark, unless you go slightly too far!

I have a Kitchenaid cooktop. Same problem, but only some of the time. Basically there is some sort of sensor that is detecting - or rather, not detecting - the flame. When it thinks there is a problem it turns on the spark igniter.
For some reason which I have never found out, but which I suspect is simply to save a few pennies by using one mechanism to control all the burners at one time, many cooktops ignite all burners at the same time. That is perfectly safe - it ignites the burner that needs ignition, burners that are totally off have no effect (because no gas) and burners that already burning properly have no effect (because adding a spark to an existing flame doesn't do much).
I find this happens almost exclusively on the two smallest burners (of 5) and sometimes on the inner small burner of the combination small/super large burner. Generally I find that when it happens I can turn the gas up a bit on the problem burner until the clicking stops and then gradually turn it down a bit every few minutes until I get to the desired level.
I suspect there is some cleaning that would help, at least in some cases. But other than that, as long as the flames burn properly (blue in a circle) it is an annoyance and not a safety issue.

This seems very likely.   A lot of cooktops will turn off the gas if they don't detect heat. I suppose turning on the spark is a friendlier idea if there is some safety logic around it. I've never seen it though, I think that's cool. And easy to imagine that the logic sometimes gets it wrong, like when it thinks there is no heat but there is in fact very little heat.

@jay613 Exactly. The highest end cooktops close the gas valve if they detect non-ignition after a certain amount of time. Which also means that they can't be turned on without electricity. Which causes problems (a) for anyone during a power outage when having a gas cooktop should let you be able to cook and (b) for Jewish holidays where lighting a burner from another flame is permitted but electronic ignition is not permitted.

My high-end cooktop that will shut down a burner without a flame present (in a bit) happily lights with a Bic lighter and keeps going in a power outage.

@JonCuster It likely varies by manufacturer. I know when I was last shopping for a Kitchenaid (replacing the previous Kitchenaid that was basically rusting out), the highest-end model at the time had the auto-shutoff feature and clearly said in the manual that it could not be lit with a match when power was off.

@manassehkatz — those same high-end stoves mostly all have Sabbath Mode to solve the (b) problem. 

@SteveI Yes and no. Ovens (and the oven part of a combined oven/cooktop) typically do. Cooktops are a different beast with somewhat different Halachic and technical issues.
